# Max motor voltage for RoboClaw controller

Tags: control, motor

The RoboClaw [data sheet](http://downloads.basicmicro.com/docs/roboclaw_datasheet_2x60A.pdf) from [ServoCity](https://www.servocity.com/roboclaw-2x60a-motor-controller) mentions various current limits, but what about voltage? Can I run a 110 Vdc treadmill motor?

Comment: first page has this specification `Up to 34VDC Operation`

Comment: Does “operation” mean the output voltage?

Comment: i am sure that it means `operated by` or `powered by` .... in other words, maximum power supply voltage

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned on page 7 of the [datasheet](http://downloads.ionmc.com/docs/roboclaw_datasheet_2x30A.pdf),

> The main power input can be from 6VDC to 34VDC on a standard RoboClaw and 10.5VDC to 60VDC or 80VDC on an HV (High Voltage) RoboClaw.

Comment: Is it safe to assume the motor output voltage is not greater than the input voltage?